# Making an array of all of the <p> tags font-sizes in my html

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make an array of all of the p tags font-sizes in my html?
the p elements (no their parents)

Comment: have you tried anything? `document.getElementsByTagName...` something?

Comment: You weren't very clear. Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to do?

Comment: What isn't working with your tries? Please share them with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this ->

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

```
var para = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
fonts=[];
for(i=0;i<para.length;i++) {
var style = window.getComputedStyle(para[i], null);

 fonts.push(style['font-size']);
}

console.log(fonts);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1us76t0g/1/

Even if there are no inline styles defined - this way you could collect font-size values in array....

Comment: <ThankYouNevermind> !Works! </ThanksAlot ( :>